# Magento certification versions?

Tags: certification

Which magento versions are the certifications based on for both the plus and regular versions?

Are the 1.6 for regular and 1.12 for enterprise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of December 2013 it's **Magento 1.7CE** for Developer and **Magento 1.12EE** for DevPlus.

Source: http://www.magentocommerce.com/certification/developer

Comment: Although the link above still says (as of June 2014) Magento 1.7, when I sat the exam recently the intro screen said 1.8.  The differences between 1.7 and 1.8 are pretty minor from a developer point of view though, so the version bump shouldn't have affected the content of the exam at all.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much the latest versions. Although the above answer is technically correct, you can expect challenge questions to include some stuff from whatever the latest release is.

Don't forget to study what a nominal product means...